# mysql query to round based specific decimal values

Tags: mysql, rounding, decimal-point

Can I round up value based specific decimal values,I have this data in my mysql table :

```
1122.46
4599.99
2000.56
5249.99
```

and I want query the result like this :

```
1122.46
4600
2000.56
5250
```

where only values which have .99 decimal point is rounded up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I could think of is:

```
SELECT `number` + (FLOOR(`number` + 0.01)-FLOOR(`number`))*0.01
```

Testing it:

`5249.99 + (FLOOR(5249.99 + 0.01)-FLOOR(5249.99))*0.01` = 5250

`1122.46 + (FLOOR(1122.46 + 0.01)-FLOOR(1122.46))*0.01` = 1122.46

Answer (score 1):

You could use a case:

```
select number + case when number - floor(number) = .99 then .01 else 0 end
```